# abandoned-cart-email-is-not-sending-to-customer in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have install and set up the abandoned cart as per the documentation but the customer did't receive any mail after adding product in cart 
Here are my settings
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using any extension , also are you sending emails from server or with `any smtp kind of extensions` ? is cron is working ?

Comment: @Baby in Magento ya i'am using an extension the mail are sending from server

Comment: check mails are going to spam or not, also contact extension developers once..... also i tried this [extension1](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart-follow-up-emails-1.html) & [extension2](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-carts-notifications-1.html) before and both worked fine for me.....